# Alternative to recursive regex replace query in presto

Tags: sql, optimization, presto

How can I get rid of this recursive regex replace function in the below presto SQL query with more elegant SQL design patterns?

```sql
SELECT
regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(
                url, 
                'pattern1', 'replacement1'
            ), 
            'pattern2', 'replacement2'
        ), 
        'pattern3', 'replacement3'
    ), 
    'pattern4', 'replacement4'
) AS deidentified_url
FROM user_requests_tb
```

We can assume that each url matches only 1 pattern

Comment: While the above is not recursive, recursion could be used to iteratively apply `regexp_replace` with a list of argument tuples.  See: https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html

Comment: Sorry. If you want only to apply one pattern per string, you could `JOIN` on the list of patterns to apply just the matching pattern, assuming one does match.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is without recursion, to just apply the pattern which matches the string (assumption in question is only one pattern will match):

1. `list` is just a way to provide the replacement list.
2. `args` provides a string to apply the replacements.
3. `doit` is the logic which applies just the matching patterns from the `list`
4. The final query expression shows the result for those matching cases.

```
WITH list (id, arg1, arg2) AS (
        SELECT 1, 'c1', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 2, 'd1', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 3, 'e1', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 4, 'f1', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 5, 'g1', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 6, 'h1', 'x'
     )
   , args (start_str) AS (
        SELECT 'abcde1fghijklmnop'
     )
   , doit (str) AS (
        SELECT regexp_replace(start_str, arg1, arg2)
          FROM args
          JOIN list
            ON regexp_like(args.start_str, list.arg1)
     )
SELECT * FROM doit
;
```

Result:

```
+------------------+
| str              |
+------------------+
| abcdxfghijklmnop |
+------------------+
1 row in set
```

If you have a version of presto (like trino) that has support for `WITH RECURSIVE`, here's an example of how recursion could be used to apply lists of replacements with a variable number of replacements.

1. `list` is just a way to provide the replacement list.
2. `args` provides a string to apply the replacements.
3. `doit` is the recursive logic which iterates over the `list`
4. The final query expression shows all the results (0, 1 to n).

```
WITH RECURSIVE list (id, arg1, arg2) AS (
        SELECT 1, 'c', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 2, 'd', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 3, 'e', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 4, 'f', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 5, 'g', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 6, 'h', 'x'
     )
   , args (start_str) AS (
        SELECT 'abcdefghijklmnop'
     )
   , doit (n, str) AS (
        SELECT 0  , start_str FROM args UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1, regexp_replace(str, arg1, arg2)
          FROM doit
          JOIN list
            ON list.id = n+1
     )
SELECT * FROM doit
 ORDER BY n
;
```

Result:

```
+------+------------------+
| n    | str              |
+------+------------------+
|    0 | abcdefghijklmnop |
|    1 | abxdefghijklmnop |
|    2 | abxxefghijklmnop |
|    3 | abxxxfghijklmnop |
|    4 | abxxxxghijklmnop |
|    5 | abxxxxxhijklmnop |
|    6 | abxxxxxxijklmnop |
+------+------------------+
7 rows in set
```

The same SQL with the last step adjusted:

4. The final query expression just grabs the last version of the replaced string.

```
WITH RECURSIVE list (id, arg1, arg2) AS (
        SELECT 1, 'c', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 2, 'd', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 3, 'e', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 4, 'f', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 5, 'g', 'x' UNION
        SELECT 6, 'h', 'x'
     )
   , args (start_str) AS (
        SELECT 'abcdefghijklmnop'
     )
   , doit (n, str) AS (
        SELECT 0  , start_str FROM args UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1, regexp_replace(str, arg1, arg2)
          FROM doit
          JOIN list
            ON list.id = n+1
     )
SELECT * FROM doit
 ORDER BY n DESC
 LIMIT 1
;
```

Result:

```
+------+------------------+
| n    | str              |
+------+------------------+
|    6 | abxxxxxxijklmnop |
+------+------------------+
1 row in set
```